# Splitting on column into multiple coloums from a CSV file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to using powershell and I am in need of some assistance.

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
DisplayName,AllJSSUSers,ALLMobileDevices,LimitToUsers,Exclusions,DepartmentEx,IconURL,ID 
Aurasma,TRUE,TRUE,"G_Year 4,G_Year 7,G_Year 11,G_Year 6,G_Year 10,G_Year 5,G_Year 9,G_Teaching Staff,G_Year 8,G_Supply Teachers,G_Year 3,G_Year 12",,,,5
```

What I would like to do is split the column "LimitToUsers" where the commas are into multiple column and then output that to a new csv file.

I have no idea where to start with this. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Gavin

Comment: Please paste the header line and a sample data row directly into your question, with correct formatting. (Screen shots are next to useless.)

Comment: Apologies I hope the below is of better use.

DisplayName,AllJSSUSers,ALLMobileDevices,LimitToUsers,Exclusions,DepartmentEx,IconURL,ID
Aurasma,TRUE,TRUE,"G_Year 4,G_Year 7,G_Year 11,G_Year 6,G_Year 10,G_Year 5,G_Year 9,G_Teaching Staff,G_Year 8,G_Supply Teachers,G_Year 3,G_Year 12",,,,5

Comment: @gavin.howson: edit your question.

Comment: Please use proper formatting for the CSV file sample you pasted. (To format as code, indent each line 4 spaces.)

Comment: Start outlining your expected results. This will also show there are more questions behind your question, e.g.: how should the new column be named?

Answer (score 1):

- You can read CSV data with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6).
- You can access that column from each data object by accessing the `LimitToUsers` property.
- You can split a string with the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6).
- You can add new properties to object with `Add-Member`.
- You can write CSV with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6).

Since you somehow have to split a single column into multiple ones, how you do that is up to you and I can't help you there

Comment: Thank you. As a complete novice I'm not sure how to write it.

I assume I start here...

Import-Csv "iPadScopedApps.csv"
Select-Object -Property LimitToUsers

how then will i write the split line. Sorry I know this is the basics but I'm only just getting into it.

Comment: Split your problem into tractable parts, figure out how to solve these parts and ask questions if you're stuck. Since you cannot even *describe* your approach to solve the problem, I'd suggest you start there. See for example Eric Lippert's great article on that subject: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/.

Comment: I have tried doing some research on this but I have no idea how I get the LimitToUsers property to be usable by the split operator. This is basically the first time using powershell so its all a bit over my head.